# For a nginx server , how to protect static resources with REST login?

Tags: rest, nginx, uwsgi

I have a nginx server running uwsgi and a python backend. I have a REST-API which is protected by login which returns a session cookie.

Now I can see a problem in that some resources are free to download even if not authenticated. Resources which are simply returned as static content by nginx.

I would like to protect the site so that all resources require a valid session cookie to be set.

Is there a way to hookup nginx to check with the python backend before returning the static resource?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need the python backend to serve the file after authentication has been verified. Take a look here for question very similar to yours:

https://serverfault.com/questions/332631/how-can-i-protect-files-on-my-nginx-server